# Can you find the Intelligence Squared podcast?

Tags: rss, podcasts

There's a link on this page http://www.intelligencesquared.com/events/catholic-church to the "Intelligence Squared podcast", but it's some strange link that works only in iTunes. I have Rhythmbox. Can anyone find the actual RSS feed? I assume there's an RSS feed in there somewhere.

Comment: There's a distinction between US and British here; both are named "intelligence squared" with the US provided, I think, through NPR as below and the British is via NPR.  I can only find the British series on YouTube but can't seem to find a subscription...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I booted into Windows, downloaded iTunes, subscribed to the podcast, right-clicked on the podcast and selected "Copy podcast URL". Pasted into a browser address bar, and had a look at it. It's http://iq2.podbean.com/feed/. And this feed is linked to from http://iq2.podbean.com/. The "subscribe in iTunes" button there is the normal type, which links to the feed directly, using the itpc: pseudo-protocol which Rhythmbox also understands.

So I booted back into Ubuntu and subscribed without difficulty.

I really don't understand why the main IQ2 site can't have a normal link like that, instead of making us jump through hoops.

Answer (score 2):

NPR provide a podcast of Intelligence Squared debates here:

http://www.npr.org/rss/podcast/podcast_detail.php?siteId=7457039

Comment: Perhaps you can share some of the details described in the podcast?

Answer (score 1):

It may be that their RSS feed is not publicly accessible and they only want you to get it via iTunes.

Comment: I get it on my Windows machine and my Windows Phone 8 device, just have to use the NPR feed.

Answer (score 0):

For clarity, posting details for the answer.

the podcast:

https://www.intelligencesquared.com/podcasts/

The feed:

https://rss.acast.com/intelligencesquared